# Behavior of indentation in Org

Tags: org-mode, indentation

I use Emacs 27.2 and Org 9.4.6. Since a very recent update of Org, I noticed a strange change in the behavior of indentation. In my init file, I have set the variable `org-adapt-indentation` to `'headline-data`; and I don't use `org-indent-mode`. Here is the (new?) behavior I noticed:

1. Type some text which does *not* follow an empty line an hit `TAB`: nothing happens (which is the expected behavior).
2. Type some text which *does* follow an empty line an hit `TAB`: this text gets indented according to the current headline level (why?).

Point 2. has an unpleasant side effect: when you still use the old template expansion mechanism for code blocks (the one provided by `org-tempo.el`, e.g. type `<s` and then hit `TAB` to expand a full source code block), those code blocks now get indented according to the headline level (because of `TAB`, I guess), which I'm sure was not the case until a very recent change.

A little screenshot to illustrate that:
[image]

The Org documentation for `org-adapt-indentation` looks unclear to me, and I'm pretty sure that typing `<s TAB` triggers both the template expansion *and* the (unwanted) code block indentation is not the expected behavior.

Is it a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I really liked the screenshot animation you illustrated your question with. Would you mind sharing how you did it?

Comment: It was recorded as an animated gif with Peek (https://github.com/phw/peek), and the keys were captured with Screenkey (https://gitlab.com/screenkey/screenkey)

Comment: I have the same bug with emacs 28.0.50 and org 9.4.6. An other reference for the supposed behavior of org-adapt-identation is the  [org-mode FAQ](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#indentation).

Somebody, may be you, asked the question [in org-mode mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2021-07/msg00188.html). It is unanswered as far as today.

Comment: It's me, yep! ;-) Since then, I found other references to that, and some folks say that it's the expected behavior (which does not sounds very logical to me, and not even in accordance with the docstring). For instance: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55413/org-mode-how-to-expand-s-after-heading-without-indentation